# Quickbooks QBFC and Inventory Turnover

Tags: inventory, qbfc

Is there a way to get the average inventory stock status in a specific timespan using Quickbooks QBFC? I've yet to find a way and no forums seem to tough the subject...

I'm asking this because I need to create an app that calculates the inventory turnover ratio per inventory item, and what I'm missing is, as mentioned before, a way to get the average stock status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking at this the wrong way, Instead of using the QBFC to access the Inventory data (which will always be current), I needed to access the reports on it, specifically the InventoryValoration report. Hope this helps someone.